# How to add Account Reference in QuickBooks while adding bills from c# application

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

I am using Quickbooks Desktop 18.0 and I am syncing data between my c# application and QuickBooks via Web Connector.

I have one task where I have to push bills and I have predefined account reference for each expenses row in Bill under Vendors -> Bills.

I am unable to push the Bills because, I am getting error like this

> 0x80040400: QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML
>   text stream

The error caused due to middot separator in Account reference. Account reference name is

> EXPENDITURE:Marketing:858700 · Advertising

Look between **858700** and **Advertising**. If I remove the `<AccountRef>` tag from the BillAddRq XML, Bill is pushed and If I replace the middot with dash then I get error like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<QBXML>
<QBXMLMsgsRs>
<BillAddRs statusCode="3140" statusSeverity="Error" statusMessage="There is an invalid reference to QuickBooks Account &quot;EXPENDITURE:Marketing:858700 - Advertising&quot; in the Bill.  QuickBooks error message: Invalid argument.  The specified record does not exist in the list." />
</QBXMLMsgsRs>
</QBXML>
```

I need to push Bill along with Account reference.

What should I do?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things here --

1. You can't just change an account name randomly, and expect it to work. So don't just swap out random characters (e.g. the bullet point) for a -dash- and expect it to work.
2. Whoever gave you that account name gave you the wrong data. The account name is actually: `EXPENDITURE:Marketing:Advertising`. They copy/pasted something off of a report in QuickBooks and gave you the `Account Number` *and* the `Account Name` fields smushed together (by that bullet dot). The actual account name alone does not include the bullet dot.
3. In the future, if you do an `AccountQuery` against QuickBooks, you can look at the `FullName` that you get back and see the actual account names you should be using, vs. relying on the data someone is sending you/you're seeing in the UI that's formatted with the account number plus the account name together.